# Call php function in javascript without waiting for response

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, post

I know how to use $.ajax. I have a Codeigniter project so I just call:

```
url:'<?php echo base_url()."somecontroller/somefunction"?>',
```

This is all ok but ajax waits for the response. I just want to the call the url as you would by typing it in your browser. I don't want to wait for the response because the controller does a redirect and then loads a view. Also i need to be able to send some data via POST.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, show your complete `$.ajax` call, not just the `url` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following for sending asynchronous request with additional parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data, // additional parameters 
    async:true,
    success: function(response){    
    }
});
```

Comment: As long as the OP doesn't post all ajax parameters it's just guesswork.

Comment: Erm, no. Not remotely. Becos, server-side scripting will be parsed by PHP before the web server daemon outputs it to the client, even locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the request to be synchronous, set `async:false`.
For post, `type:POST`

Refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: OP doesn't want to wait, so it needs to be asynchronous. As long as the OP doesn't post all ajax parameters it's just guesswork. Also, wrong type: `type:'POST'`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can try this ?
Change the (alert) function with your function

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'test.html',
            async: false,
            success: function () { alert('hello people from the world'); }
        });
```

**Never** use async: false.
Since Javascript runs on the UI thread, an async: false request will freeze the browser until the server replies