# Send data to php function with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

I want to send some data to a php function with javascript. I have already post a question about this earlier today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15243535/847773), though I didnt get a satisfactory answer, maybe didnt explain myself right.

So I have some variables in javascript( I get it through some API). I would like to send this variables to a function in php. I am using codeigniter so I call the function like("somecontroller/somefunction").

I would like the send the data through post to the function. The function calls a view and reloads the whole html. I am looking for something like sending a form. Only I have the variables in javascript. If there isnt any other way I will dynamicly create a form with jquery and send the data with the .click method on the submit button. But is there a more elegant solution??

I know about ajax, but the problem is that I dont want a asynchronous request I want to just submit the data and then for the new html to load.

Comment: do you want to reload the page entirely or just some parts?

Comment: I want to load the page entirely

Comment: Creating a form is the thing to do, but you can submit it via the `.submit()` method on the form's DOM element. No need to make a fake "submit" button. I *think* you need to actually append the form to the real DOM for this to work, so you'll want to make it invisible somehow.

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery? It makes it easy.

Comment: the form can be invisible I would just use hidden fields. I am using jQuery btw.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use `$.post()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think to solve this would be to send the data through the query string, although you'd have to change the target page to accept GET or REQUEST instead of just POST.

To do this just:

```
window.location.href = 'somecontroller/somefunction?var1='+var1+'&var2='+var2;
```

Comment: I would prefer to send this data through post

Comment: Then you might have to do something awkward like create a hidden form, populate it and then submit it, or do an ajax call then redirect the page once that's completed.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this link how to pass arguments to your controller methods in CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri). Then just redirect user to this link.

If you want to redirect through the Form, set action of form to your controller and in php you can access your form elements through `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using jQuery:

```
$.post("somecontroller/somefunction", {
    param1: var1,
    param2: var2,
    ...

}, function(result) { ... });
```

Comment: This is like ajax, it doesnt load the html in the browser.

Comment: I wonder if `$(document).load("somecontroller/somefunction", ...)` will work.