# Run long SAS stored proc from php without hanging browser

Tags: php, ajax, linux, yii, sas

I need to call a SAS stored proc that takes about 5 minutes to run without hanging up my browser. I'm using a Yii stack and calling SAS through a url. I'd attach code, but honestly I've tried so many things at this point that there's not a version of my code that makes any sense anymore. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I've tried exec() and that doesn't seem to work. I've tried ajax, and would prefer an async ajax call, but at this point I'll try anything. Any other information that is needed, just let me know.

UPDATE: I created a controller action in php that successfully completes the stored process if I go directly to the controller action in the url of the browser. However, if I call that controller action with an ajax get, the stored process doesn't execute.

Comment: if my answer is unsuitable (eg, you need URL based parameters and cannot edit your STP) please post your attempt at using ajax..

Comment: I'm confused about your use of PHP - are you calling the SAS Stored Proc from the client browser or a PHP server?

Answer (score 1):

ajax should work fine!  You can even try using the SASjs [javascript library](https://github.com/sasjs/adapter). More details on the [website](https://sasjs.io).  Example code - once configured - is as follows:

```
var adapter = new SASjs.default({
     appLoc: "/SASFolder/appLocation"
    ,serverType:"SAS9"
}); // Can be SAS9 or Viya

var dataObj = {tableName: [{ colName: 'colValue' }]}; // can be null
adapter.request('/subfolder/servicename',dataObj)
.then((response) => {
  //we just submitted a request, now deal with response
  alert(response);
  // all code here will execute AFTER the STP / JES is finished
});
// all code here will execute immediately
```

Comment: Let me try to be a little clearer, sorry. I'm using ajax to call the php controller which makes the SAS call. The reason I'm doing this is that calling the SAS url with ajax gives me a CORS error and I'm pretty sure would hang up my browser while the SAS process runs. Am I wrong? And I am using parameters in the url string.

Comment: it wouldn't necessarily hang your browser, but there would be a CORS issue if the page wasn't served by the SAS web server.  Can you add your domain as an exception? Or disable same origin policy for testing?  Afraid I can't help with the php side.. But either way, it sill sounds to me like you just need to wrap the whole thing in an event handler (in the browser, using javascript).  If you could add a new question, showing what you've tried (ajax wise) then I think you will get a much better response from the field..

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the SAS Stored Procedure successfully from php then you just need to call your php service asynchronously from javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + '&_action=background',
    data: data, // additional parameters 
    async:true,
    success: function(response){  
     alert(response); 
     // all code here will execute AFTER the PHP/STP is finished
    }
});
// all code here will execute immediately
```

credit to @[angel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243535/call-php-function-in-javascript-without-waiting-for-response)

Edit: adding _action=background to URL following @quentin's suggestion

Comment: Problem with this is that the ajax call waits for the SAS process to finish. If I try to leave the page it cuts off the ajax call which stops the script apparently. Doesn't make sense to me, so I know I'm missing something.

Comment: Also, it hangs on the page. I can't navigate away. It just spins until the process finishes.

Comment: @JonSkinner If they navigate away, what's the issue with the script stopping?  There's no way for the results to be returned at that point without it being run again.

Comment: presumably the results are being written elsewhere..  I've also had issues with STPs stopping server-side, which involved a bit of fiddling with the load balancing options.

Comment: @RawFocus is right, a pdf document is being written somewhere else. The idea is that I'll have a watchdog script that sends an alert that the pdf is finished processing and the user can download. I guess since php is single threaded maybe the whole stack is locking up to wait for the SAS process to finish? But that really doesn't make sense since I'm assuming the php controller doesn't require a response to be sent back.

Comment: if you want to keep the request server side (in php) to avoid a dependency on the browser staying alive / on the same page, and you don't have the capacity to modify the SAS configuration, then it sounds like you have narrowed this down to a php 'exec' issue.  I'd suggest posting this as a new question, with an example of what you have tried..

Comment: Y'all are out of my league. Could adding _action=background to the URL calling the stored process possibly help?